# Facing Problems on installing Apache Spark-1.6.0 by sbt/sbt assembly command. Error: Cannot load main class from JAR

Tags: java, scala, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Ubuntu and apache Spark.
I installed **Spark-1.1.0** correctly on my laptop. Now i want to upgrade it to **Apache spark-1.6.0 version**.
my Java version:

```
    harshit@black-viper:~$ java -version
    java version "1.7.0_101"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6)(7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
    harshit@black-viper:~$
```

my **Scala version**:

```
    harshit@black-viper:~$ scala -version
    Scala code runner version 2.11.7 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
    harshit@black-viper:~$
```

I updated my **Git** also, then I installed **py4j package**. I run following codes for Spark-1.6.0

```
    $ wget http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.6.0.tgz
    $ tar xvf spark-1.6.0.tgz
    $ cd spark-1.6.0/
    $ sbt/sbt assembly
```

and then when I tried to run **pi example**. i got this error:

```
    harshit@black-viper:~/spark-1.6.0$ ./bin/run-example SparkPi 10
    Failed to find Spark examples assembly in /home/harshit/spark-1.1.0/lib or /home/harshit/spark-1.1.0/examples/target
    You need to build Spark before running this program
    harshit@black-viper:~/spark-1.6.0$
```

When I tried to open pyspark, I got this error:

```
    harshit@black-viper:~/spark-1.6.0$ ./bin/pyspark
    Error: Cannot load main class from JAR: file:/home/harshit/spark-1.6.0/pyspark-shell-main
    Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
    harshit@black-viper:~/spark-1.6.0$
```

**Can some please explain me what should I do now to resolve this.** I guess i have spark-1.1.0 installed so it is merging both versions.

Comment: Why can't you use a prebuilt version of spark? In the download options just use prebuilt for hadoop 2.6.0 (or some other version that you require).

Comment: Do you have `SPARK_HOME` var in your environment? Usually when it cannot find a `jar` you've missed the class path.

Comment: I tried installing pre-build version spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4 and getting same JAR error.